# Android Developer Studio: gradle build waits long before the "real" build process starts

Tags: android, gradle, build

looks like the usual question of slow builds, I know. But I have found no solution somewhere, the build itself is fast, it just needs to start building!

When I run gradle with "--debug", the build process starts with several lines, then stops:

```
...
2023-10-05T07:17:11.293+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Evaluate settings' started
2023-10-05T07:17:11.293+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.locking.LockFileReaderWriter] Lockfiles root: C:\dev\Android\Projects\go-eLocal\gradle\dependency-locks
2023-10-05T07:17:19.404+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.404+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.405+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.405+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.405+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.406+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

and the block of the last 7 lines might be repeated every 10 seconds for a few times (CPU idle),

```
...
2023-10-05T07:17:11.293+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Evaluate settings' started
2023-10-05T07:17:11.293+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.locking.LockFileReaderWriter] Lockfiles root: C:\dev\Android\Projects\go-eLocal\gradle\dependency-locks
2023-10-05T07:17:19.404+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.404+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.405+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.405+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.405+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:19.406+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:29.402+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:29.402+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:29.403+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:29.404+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:29.404+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-10-05T07:17:29.405+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

then the build process continues very fast. Thus the computer sits idly waiting for something ("Evaluate settings"?) to happen, until after 10-60 (!) seconds it starts building.

What should happen, and what could I do to make this happen? ;)

The lines above the "idle" is:

```
...
2023-10-05T07:24:43.567+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar from candidates [gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=17, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.plugin.api-version=8.2.1, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
2023-10-05T07:24:43.567+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Resolve files of classpath'
2023-10-05T07:24:43.567+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Resolve files of classpath' completed
2023-10-05T07:24:43.568+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Apply plugin JetGradlePlugin to build' started
2023-10-05T07:24:43.569+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin JetGradlePlugin to build'
2023-10-05T07:24:43.569+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Apply plugin JetGradlePlugin to build' completed
2023-10-05T07:24:43.569+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Apply initialization script 'C:\Users\chk\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' to build'
2023-10-05T07:24:43.569+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Apply initialization script 'C:\Users\chk\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' to build' completed
2023-10-05T07:24:43.569+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.locking.LockFileReaderWriter] Lockfiles root: C:\dev\Android\Projects\go-eLocal\gradle\dependency-locks
2023-10-05T07:24:43.570+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Apply initialization script 'C:\Users\chk\AppData\Local\Temp\ijtestinit.gradle' to build' started
2023-10-05T07:24:43.570+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Apply initialization script 'C:\Users\chk\AppData\Local\Temp\ijtestinit.gradle' to build'
2023-10-05T07:24:43.570+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Apply initialization script 'C:\Users\chk\AppData\Local\Temp\ijtestinit.gradle' to build' completed
2023-10-05T07:24:43.570+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Run init scripts'
2023-10-05T07:24:43.570+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Run init scripts' completed
2023-10-05T07:24:43.570+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Evaluate settings' started
2023-10-05T07:24:43.570+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.locking.LockFileReaderWriter] Lockfiles root: C:\dev\Android\Projects\go-eLocal\gradle\dependency-locks
```

So the "LockFileReaderWriter" does only block after the "Build operation 'Evaluate settings' started"...

My gradle properties:

```
android.debug.obsoleteApi=true
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.enableJetifier=false
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.vfs.watch=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:+UseParallelGC\
org.gradle.configuration-cache=false
org.gradle.configuration-cache.problems=warn
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

The project itself consistes of 4 sub-modules, but these build fast - it's just the idle process at the start.

This began several months ago, I cannot tell what happened then (if I changed something, or if an update occurred, ...)

My machine is a 16 core CPU (actually 16+8), has 32 GB RAM and an SSD. It's not the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

For others: this was due to some network drives that were not available (i.e. the IP address was not valid any more) - solved.
Gradle should not try to check all available drives.